# I there any way to ignore some fields at all with Simple REST Data Provider

Tags: react-admin

We want to exclude some fields from getting send back during PUT update calls.

Is it possible to define a kind of a model as a list of fields and exclude all the other fields at all? So they don't even are stored in the redux-store?

Best without building our own Data Provider?

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash to specify which fields you are interested in

```js
const target = _.pick(source, ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']);
```

or to specify which fields you are NOT interested in

```js
const target = _.omit(source, ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']);
```

If you can live with a simple oneliner that is.   Not sure if you are rather looking for  a more scaleable framework type solution tho